# Why is `handleChangedUser` function in Form not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to edit users information. But when I do `handleChangedUser` function it doesn't work but if I change it to `handleNameChange` function it does work.

How can I fix it?

This is my github repo to that project: https://github.com/gumutzkn/test.

**Code:**

```
export default function EditUser() {
  const { users } = useContext(UserContext);
  const {
    name,
    username,
    email,
    city,
    number,
    setName,
    setUserName,
    setEmail,
    setCity,
  } = useContext(EditUserContext);

  function handleNameChange(e) {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleUserNameChange(e) {
    setUserName(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleEmailChange(e) {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    const selectedUser = users.find(item => item.id === number);

    selectedUser.email = e.target.value;
  }

  function handleCityChange(e) {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleChangedUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("target hit");
    const selectedUser = users.find(item => item.id === number);

    selectedUser.name = name;
  }

  return (
    <div className="edit">
      <h4>Edit User</h4>
      <form onSubmit={handleChangedUser}>
        <div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleNameChange}
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleUserNameChange}
            type="text"
            name="username"
            value={username}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleEmailChange}
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="input-field">
          <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleCityChange}
            type="text"
            name="city"
            value={city}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          style={{ margin: "2rem 1rem" }}
          className="btn waves-effect cyan waves-light right"
          type="submit"
          name="action">
          Save
          <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don’t see a handle submit function in the code example?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  It _should_ run with an `onClick` prop on your input element.

Comment: I think OP is trying to say that `handleChangedUser`, which is form submit handler, is not working.

Comment: What do you want `handleChangedUser` function to do? Do you want it to clear the data in `users`?

Comment: `handleChangedUser` is not working i mean. I want it to do change users input when click the button or submit the form. when i transfer  what `handleChangedUser` has into `handleNameChange` it is working while i am texting in input. I couldn't find any solition to do that. In  `users` array there are users data from an API. All i want is to change `users` datas when i type something into `input` and submit the form. You can look at my github link if that can be clear for you.

Comment: `function handleChangedUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("target hit");
    const selectedUser = users.find(item => item.id === number);

    selectedUser.name = name;
  }` It should work like that but it doesn't

Comment: It is about `useEffect`. I should rerender the `users` when something is changed. But i don't know what should change

Comment: You are mutating context value directly. Instead, create new modified `users` array: `function handleChangedUser_new(e) { e.preventDefault(); setUsers((prevUsers) => prevUsers.map((user) => { if (user.id === number) { return { ...user, name: name, username: username, email: email, city: city, number: number, }; } return user; }) ); }` where `setUsers` is from context : `const { users, setUsers } = useContext(UserContext);`

Comment: WOOW!! Thanks man it is working. You are the man.